# Setting viewport width when the container is smaller than the device-width

Tags: android, ipad, ios9, viewport

I have a small webview (with approx 75px height) that displays html content with the following metadata in the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

This html will be displayed on webviews across Android Phone, Android 
Tablet, iPhone and iPad.

On phone devices (Android Phone/iPhone), the webview container width is the same as the device width,  so the above viewport meta data tag appears to work fine.

But on tablet devices (Android Tablet/iPad), the webview container width will be dynamic, so sometimes the webview container width will be smaller than the device width.

This means on tablet, whenever the webview container width is smaller than the device width, the html content ***should*** be cropped.

However after altering the metadata to have either

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=50, initial-scale=1" />
```

or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1" />
```

I found that the metadata seems to actually be ignored on Android and  iPhones/iPads with iOS9. This means the content will adjust and appear as expected on all of these devices. I can only see this issue on iPads pre iOS9.

I've tried removing the viewport metadata tag, and I've also tried using the following metadata tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=100%, initial-scale=1" />
```

and both work fine, but I was wondering if there was any cleaner solution  as I've been recommended not to alter or remove the viewport metadata that I am currently using.